# RadMenu populated with List as Itemssource access name from code behind when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have been looking all over for an answer to my question, what I want might not be possible but I am just giving it a try.
I am working on a webservice and I want to have a dynamically generated RadMenuItem where if I click on one of the elements, a document belonging to that elements name will open. 
I managed to create the RadMenuItems dynamically and use the click event to have something happen when I click on it. This looks like this in xaml

```
<telerik:RadMenuItem Header ="{Binding Resources.Documentation, Source={StaticResource strings}}" ItemsSource ="{Binding Documentnames}" 
                                     Tag="Name" Click="OnClick" Name="Name" />
```

And the method in the code behind for OnClick looks like this

```
private void OnClick(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //I want to give the string value of the clicked event to the GetDocumentation method below.
        MainMenuViewModel.GetDocumentation();
    }
```

Now as it says in the code, I want to know the Name (a String value) to give as a parameter to the method. Does anyone know how to do this. Using the sender and casting it to RadMenuItem and doing .Name will return the string "Name". For questions, don't hesitate to ask, I have tried to explain it as clear as possible, but it is difficult to make it understandable in text.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you can cast sender to RadMenuItem, is not it enough?

Comment: I know and that is what I am trying to use, and what would be the logical thing to do. I will explain a little bit more. The content of Documentnames is a list with Strings. When I use Name = "Name"; the Strings will be shown as names of the subradmenuitems on the webserver. However, when I try to extract the name in the code behind, it will just return the string name. I can't seem to find the value that was clicked anywhere in the radmenuitem object sender.

Comment: Ah I found it! Finally!!! I had to use the Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e instead of the Sender and ask for the Header instead of the name! Thanks anyway and maybe this will help someone else!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use the Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e instead of the Sender and ask for the Header instead of the name, maybe this will help someone else having the same issue!